# Get all combinations of rows in a

Tags: r, dataframe

My actual dataframe contains some 100 rows and dozens of columns. An example dataframe:

```
tg1_a = c(1.4, 1.6, 1.1, 4, 4.5, 5, 8, 9.1)
tg2_a = c(1.1, 2.6, 1.7, 5, 4.9, 5, 9, 8.4)
tg3_a = c(1.9, 1.9, 1.8, 6, 3.6, 5, 7.9, 9.9)
gene = c("gene1", "gene2", "gene3", "gene4", "gene5", "gene6", "gene7", "gene8")
df = data.frame(gene, tg1_a, tg2_a, tg3_a)
```

How can I get all combinations of rows in this dataframe?
I have tried the `expand.grid` and `combn` functions but without any success.

My desired output would be (for the gene column):

```
gene = c("gene1", "gene2", "gene1, "gene3", "gene1", "gene4", "gene1", "gene5", ... etc)
```

And so on for all combinations!

I would like to keep all the other columns intact in the output dataframe.

I understand that it will be a very very large df, so a faster method is desired.

Comment: The output df did not maintained my df structure, messed up all columns, etc

Comment: Please show your expected output

Comment: How do you want to change `gene` column to have multiple `gene1`, `gene2` etc and drop `gene7` and `gene8`. Whats logic?

Comment: I do not want to drop any rows. The desired function will actually duplicate each row for as many times as required to "pair" with all other rows.

Comment: If there are thousands of rows then the number of combinations of rows is much larger than the the number of nanoseconds since big bang. I don't think you would be able to fit all such combinations in a single dataframe.

Comment: In particular, if it's as low as 2000, there are `choose(2e3, 2)` combos, which will prove unwieldy...

Comment: Hmm. I have changed my question. Can I do this if I have, say 100, genes? I will `filter` for `interesting` genes and then do this operation.

Comment: Perhaps you want `sapply(df, function(x) combn(x, 2))` ?

Comment: Your output is still unclear to me, but yes, combn like `df[c(combn(nrow(df), 2)), ]` matches what you gave for the gene column output... to avoid memory exploding, you could maybe instead use combn's FUN= argument to do your whatever your pairwise analysis is, eg `combn(nrow(df), 2, FUN = function(x) sqrt(sum(sapply(df[x, ], diff)^2)))`

Comment: @Frank. Thanks. Would like to calculate ratios between the newly created pairs.

Comment: @jaySf. This works. Thanks